# Detect first top element when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset, detect

How to **detect** first top element *(who is visible on window view)* when scrolling ?

**Like this...**

[image: detect first top element]

**I begin with..**

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce(250,function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('current').each(function() {
       //if(statement) {
       //  $(this).addClass('current')
       //}
    });
}));
```

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/EUztW/

I have no idea how to detect which first box is on top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce(250, function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var $first;
    var firstPos;

    $('.box').each(function() {
            var $box = $(this).removeClass('current');
            var pos = $box.offset();

            if(pos.top > scrollTop && (!firstPos || pos.top < firstPos.top)){
                $first = $box;
                firstPos = pos;
            }
    });

     if($first){
        $first.addClass("current");   
     }
}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EUztW/10/

Comment: +1 Thanks , But why detection "first right" box doesn't work ?

Comment: @l2aelba Sorry, that should have been `offset` and not `position`.  Updated.

Comment: Some question. If I have 1000 boxes ? What about `.each()` function ?

Comment: @l2aelba You might want to store a few things and reference them instead of requerying in each loop. For example, you could store `$(window)` once, and `$(".box")` once. Also, you should probably do the `.removeClass('current')` **inside** the main loop (like `$(this).removeClass("current")`, because `.removeClass()` has to loop interally, so it's kind of extra processing. I only say all this because the window's scrolling handler can fire very often, and this is a lot for the JS to do each time

Comment: What about this ? http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/EUztW/7/ ? Run .each() only once :D @Ian

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/EUztW/8/ , forgot to removeclass inside the loop , now fixed @Ian

Comment: @l2aelba Hah, yeah, that outer `each` wasnt' intended.  I meant to only have the one.

Answer (score -1):

You can use .offset() to find the top div.

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce(250,function(){
    var top_one;
    var offset_top = 10000;
    $('.box').removeClass('current').each(function() {
        offset = $(this).offset();
        if(offset.top < offset_top){
            offset_top = offset.top;
            top_one = $(this);
        }
    });
    top_one.addClass('current');
}));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EUztW/6/)

Comment: Did you test your code at all or just put it in a fiddle and link it? It doesn't work for me at all - the red never moves to a different box

Comment: Possibly a bit picky, but you really shouldn't name all of your variables starting with `$`, it kind of defeats the purpose.  Also, don't "re-wrap` jquery variables.  `$($top_one)` is a wasted call to jquery.

Comment: And, the reason this doesn't work at all is that you don't ever compare the element's position to the scroll position of the window.  So you always select the first div on the page regardless of scroll position.

Comment: Yeah, normally a `$` at the beginning of a variable names means it contains a jQuery object. Obviously, that's not required, but that's a normal convention. I know in PHP, variables start with `$`, but that isn't usually used in JS

Comment: @Ian : Sorry, I didn't understand the question fully. I got it. My mistake. Thanks

Comment: @JamesMontagne : Yeah, i got it. Thanks for the info. And regarding the question, I misunderstood it. Yeah, it need to compare scroll position and your answer works like a charm. Thanks for the info and your time.